# Static centered background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following css

```
.bg
{
    height:          100%;
    background:      url("${image}") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top:      -7px;
}
```

And use it as such

```
<div class = "bg"></div>
```

What I would like to have is static image like that, but then if you scroll down (the image remains), the page text starts coming up. How should I change up my css?

My page text is

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "jumbotron well">
        <div class = "page-header">
            <h3>Header
                <small>subheader</small>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
To clarify further. What I would like is a full screen centered image (Which the css does) that is also static so that if you scroll down the text can be scrolled over it.

Comment: try to add this `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: Why does it need to be inside a div? Where would this div/image go?

Comment: @Rob it doesn't have to be inside div, I just didn't know how to make a centered image that takes whole page you could scroll over

Comment: @FelixMosheev I tried to do that, however the image shrinks if I do that and doesn't take up the full page anymore

Comment: That you want it to be full page is additional information you need to add to your question.

Comment: @Rob added it. Sorry I thought it was implied from the css that I provided. I added clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `background-attachment: fixed;`.
Something like that should work.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://images.alphacoders.com/633/633643.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bg"></div>
Just text<br> Just text<br> Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just
text
<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just
text
<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>Just text<br>
```